# Apple push notification Vs. Parse

Tags: ios, push-notification

i have an app and i'm thinking about implementing push notifications in it. however, i want to use remote notifications. i've tried Parse's push notification service and it's great and works well. You can type any text you want to inform your users about and just press send in order to be delivered to all your App users. On the other hand, i don't know if Apple has any such service that can facilitate the process of sending remote notifications. so which is better to stick to, Apple or Parse? and can i have the same service as Parse from Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the same services as Parse. You have to build your own server that will talk with Apple APNS. Just for example sending a push notification from your own server without using parse is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what are you trying to ask.

You can use Apple push notification service for sending remote content. With Any content related to your App.

Check [RemoteNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html) for details. Parse is also using the Apple's push notification service.

**Edit:** For implementing your own servers for push notification check this tutorial : [Push Notification Services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: thanks for the reply. i was asking if Apple has the same push notification service as Parse which has a simple interface to send remote notification to your app users. it seems i have to come up with my own server in order to push notifications if i don't want to use parse.

Comment: Not parse. Parse is using apple's push notification using their servers. You can build your own servers and communicate with Apple servers for sending push notification.

Comment: yes i got the idea i meant the ease of pushing notifications without the hassle of creating a server if your app is a simple one using Parse. by the way, do you recommend using Parse?

Comment: @user2176995: Sure , you can use parse. It's a very useful stuff.